# How to have access to the POJO returned by a RestController method (endpoint) in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I want to be able to modify the POJO returned by a RestController method (or endpoint) before it gets serialized into the HttpServletResponse as a stream of data. But I want to be able to do it outside the controller method code (as a middleware).

I have tried to do it using a HandlerInterceptor but I do not have access there to the POJO. I have also tried using AOP but the Pointcut was never called.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public Resource<User> getTest() {
    Resource<User> resource = new Resource<>();
    resource.setData(new User("test user"));
    return resource;
  }


  @Builder
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class User {
    private String username;
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  static class Resource<T> {
    private T data;
    private Set<String> errors;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to add a list of `errors` (if needed) to the Resource returned by the Controller after the controller performs its own logic and returns.

Comment: Show the code for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the object after returned from `@RestController` method but before it is written to the HTTP response, you can implement `ResponseBodyAdvice` and declared it as  `@ControllerAdvice` bean:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public static class Foo implements ResponseBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

        //body is the object return from the @RestController method
        //Cast it and modify it accordingly.
        if(body instanceof Resource) {
            Resource res = (Resource)body;
            //Modify it .... blablablba
        }
        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.